# formatting pandas.tseries.offsets.Minute in HH:MM form

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have an offset that comes in as a pandas.tseries.offsets.Minute

As a string, it looks like this:
<34 * Minutes>
or
<-35 * Minutes>

to 00:34 or -00:35?

I can do this with parsing and integer division with 60, but is there a facility in pandas to manipulate offsets in this way -- ideally also to convert 125 to 02:05? All of my offsets are timeDelta-like if that helps.

```
def format_min(inmin):
    pat = r'\<([-\d]+)\s*\*\s*Minutes\>'
    mat = re.match(pat,str(inmin))
    orig = int(mat.group(1))
    hr,m = divmod(abs(orig),60) 
    hr = np.sign(orig)*hr
    return f"{hr}:{m}"

mymin = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('-134T')
print(format_min(mymin))
print(mymin)
```

produces

```
-2:14
<-134 * Minutes>
```

The -2:14 is what I want given the -134 minute input in the sample, but I'm hoping to avoid the trouble/stability/corner cases of doing this myself.

Comment: `pd.Timedelta(125,unit='Min')`

Comment: Can you share an example of the data? There's something I'd like to test.

Comment: Could you use regex and strip off the extra characters and get the time and convert to timedelta. I am not sure if there is any function. Maybe someone else can answer.

Comment: @davidbilla I have clarified how to do it that way, although I was hoping that formatting of the offset would be possible

Comment: @AMC The sample is the line `pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('-134T')`